# QT5.0.2 project needs more DLLs than QT4.8

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5

Recently we moved to QT 5.0.2 from QT4.8.  Our project now needs more DLL files than the earlier. It requires qml, opengl, printer modules. However we did not use any of these modules in our application. The size of exe file increased due to additional DLLs.

QT-= qml opengl -> did not exclude this module from our application.

Are these additional DLLs are compulsory for Qt 5.0.2 ? Is there any way to come out from this? We need to exclude these dlls to reduce exe size.

Comment: My bad luck. This is a bug in QT5.0.2. It is in unresolved state.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the modules you use may be dependent on those you don't, which means your project depends on them indirectly. For example, by default, some modules (QtWebKit, QtMultimedia) utilize ANGLE which uses OpenGL. You can try to trace those dependencies by using a program named Dependency Walker (available [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com)). The Qt GUI has changed a lot since 4.8, and there are now separate modules for printing and other functions (see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qtgui-index.html#qt-gui-prior-to-qt-5-0)).

Sources:

- [Qt 5 on Windows ANGLE and OpenGL](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL)
- [Qt 5 Deployment on Windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies)

By the way, someone has (had) a similar problem: http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-52102.html. (Unfortunately, there is no solution in that link.)

**It turned out that this is actually a [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28766) in Qt.**

Comment: Dependency walker did not help me to exclude modules in .pro file.

Comment: However it helped to trace dependencies.. how they are linked.. Is there any way to exclude modules(like QT-= xxx in .pro file) ?

Comment: @Mr.Prabhu I updated my answer. Adding `QT -= xxx` to the .pro file should do the trick, but I think it doesn't work if that module depends on another module (which is included in the project). In that case, you can either exclude that module as well or try reinstall or rebuild Qt with different configuration.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28766. Bug in Qt 5.0.2 and it is not resolved. Bad luck!